# Print MigraDoc document from WPF app

Tags: wpf, printing, pdfsharp, migradoc

I use PdfSharp/MigraDoc to create and view documents in an application.

I use the WPF version since I need the WPF documentviewer. Now I'd like to print the documents (which works from the DocumentViewer), but for some reason I only get empty pages when I try printing myself.

I use this code to print:

```
MigraDocPrintDocument printDocument = new MigraDocPrintDocument();
printDocument.Renderer = new DocumentRenderer(druck.GetDruck());
printDocument.Renderer.PrepareDocument();
printDocument.Print();
```

What do I need to do to print from WPF (from WinForms this worked nicely, but I need WPF for the DocumentViewer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug of MigraDoc 1.31: printing only works if you use the GDI+ build.
As a workaround you can try to use both versions - WPF build for the preview, GDI+ build for direct printing.

Comment: But using both versions from the very same assembly is mighty tricky, since they share the namespaces - isn't it?

Comment: You don't have to use both versions in the same assembly - make a new PrintHelper assembly that uses GDI+ and pass the document e.g. as a MigraDoc DDL string. See also: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocDDL.ashx